# I want to add arrays without changing the order

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
    public void moveZeroes(int[] nums, int[] arr) {
         
        for(int i =0; i<=nums.length-1; i++){
            if(nums[i]!=0) continue;
            else{
                // here will be the code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is there any method or function (or any other help) that I could write in else block that would add another array in the end of nums array without changing the order of numbers and code above.  The code above is for adding two arrays containing non zero arrays, if an array contains zero then delete the zero without changing the order.

```
Example- nums =1,9,2,0,5 ; arr= 0,4,2,7,0
Output - 1,9,2,5,4,2,7
```

Comment: Where should the resulting array be stored? Can you change the return type of this method from `void` to `int[]` and return the result array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**

You can do the concatenation of arrays and filter the `0s` out in a single line using streams. Thanks to @Eritrean for reminding me this. You can just modify your moveZeroes function like this:

```
public static int[] moveZeroes(int[] nums, int[] arr) {
    return Stream.of(nums,arr).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).filter(x-> x!=0).toArray();
}
```

**Old Answer**

You can concatenate the two arrays and then just filter the `0s` out from the resulting array using streams.

You can concatenate arrays as below:

```
int[] result = new int[nums.length+arr.length];
System.arraycopy(nums, 0, result, 0, nums.length);
System.arraycopy(arr, 0, result, nums.length, arr.length);
```

The `System.arraycopy() parameters works as follows:
The first one takes the source array, second one takes source array start Index, then destination array, destination array start index, destination array upto index+1 which is here the source array length.

After that just use stream and filter to get your expected array:

```
Arrays.stream(result)
            .filter(x -> x!=0)
            .toArray();
```

The corresponding moveZero function will look something like this:

```
public int[] moveZeroes(int[] nums, int[] arr) {
    int[] result = new int[nums.length+arr.length];
    System.arraycopy(nums, 0, result, 0, nums.length);
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, result, nums.length, arr.length);
    return Arrays.stream(result)
            .filter(x -> x!=0)
            .toArray();
}
```

The answer is what you expected:

```
[1, 9, 2, 5, 4, 2, 7]
```

Comment: If taking the stream approach, no need for a new array and coping values. Can be done in one line `return Stream.of(nums,arr).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).filter(i -> i != 0).toArray();`

Comment: Oh! Thanks, I actually forgot this beauty! Updating my answer.

Comment: can you please elaborate the updated answer , I am a beginner so its a bit overwhelming to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you should use only arrays you should know first the number of non zero elements in both of the arrays in order to determine the size of the output array. After that you just need to iterate over the arrays and to add them in a new array

```
class Solution {
    public int[] moveZeroes(int[] nums, int[] arr) {
        int nonZeroCount = 0;
        for (int n: nums) {
            if (n != 0) {
                nonZeroCount++;
            }
        }
        for (int n: arr) {
            if (n != 0) {
                nonZeroCount++;
            }
        }
        int[] result = new int[nonZeroCount];
        int i = 0;
        for (int n: nums) {
            if (n != 0) {
                result[i++] = n;
            }
        }
        for (int n: arr) {
            if (n != 0) {
                result[i++] = n;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new result array with max length of nums.length+arr.length then in the else loop through the add the values to this result array then repeat the same for arr.

```
 public void moveZeroes(int[] nums, int[] arr) {
        int result[] = new int[nums.length+arr.length];
        int index =0;
        for(int i =0; i<=nums.length-1; i++){
            if(nums[i]!=0) continue;
            else{
                // here will be the code
                result[index++] = nums[i];
            }
        }
       for(int i =0; i<=arr.length-1; i++){
            if(arr[i]!=0) continue;
            else{
                // here will be the code
                result[index++] = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

I haven't tested it. But this should give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

I can use it if you want plus to array:

```
 int[] newArr = new int[arr.length + nums.length];
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length + arr.length; i++) {
            if (i < nums.length) {
                if (nums[i] == 0) {
                    x++;
                    continue;
                } else {
                    newArr[i - x] = nums[i];
                }
            } else {
                if (arr[i - nums.length] == 0) {
                    x++;
                    continue;
                } else {
                    newArr[i - x] = arr[i - nums.length];
                }
            }
        }
        int[] arrs = new int[arr.length + nums.length-x];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrs.length; i++) {
          arrs[i]=newArr[i];
        }
return arrs;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java an **array** is **immutable** structure: you can't modify length of the array.

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] nums = { 1, 9, 2, 0, 5 };
    int[] arr = { 0, 4, 2, 7, 0 };
    int[] res = moveZeroes(nums, arr);
}

public static int[] moveZeroes(int[] nums, int[] arr) {
    int[] res = new int[calcNonZeroLength(nums) + calcNonZeroLength(arr)];
    int j = 0;

    for (int[] curArr : Arrays.asList(nums, arr))
        for (int i = 0; i < curArr.length; i++)
            if (curArr[i] != 0)
                res[j++] = curArr[i];

    return res;
}

private static int calcNonZeroLength(int[] arr) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] != 0)
            count++;

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to add a return type of array `int[]` to your method
2. create a counter variable to keep track of number of elements you have
3. Create an empty array with the length of `nums.length + arr.length` (your array may not have zero values). iterate over each array and check values if it's not zero then add to the temp array and increase the counter.
4. create a new array according to counter to remove the zero elements of `temp` array.

```
public int[] moveZeroes(int[] nums, int[] arr) {
    int[] temp = new int[nums.length + arr.length];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if(nums[i] != 0) {
            temp[count++] = nums[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] != 0) {
            temp[count++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    int [] result = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = temp[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a full example for you

'''

```
public static int[] removeTheElement(int[] arr,
                                      int index)
{

    // If the array is empty
    // or the index is not in array range
    // return the original array
    if (arr == null
        || index < 0
        || index >= arr.length) {

        return arr;
    }

    // Create another array of size one less
    int[] anotherArray = new int[arr.length - 1];

    // Copy the elements except the index
    // from original array to the other array
    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        // if the index is
        // the removal element index
        if (i == index) {
            continue;
        }

        // if the index is not
        // the removal element index
        anotherArray[k++] = arr[i];
    }

    // return the resultant array
    return anotherArray;
}


 public void moveZeroes(int[] nums, int[] arr) {
     
    for(int i =0; i<=nums.length-1; i++){
        if(nums[i]!=0) continue;
        else{
           nums = removeTheElement( nums ,  nums[i]);
        }
    }
}
```